# Strange (Unicode?) encoding in PDF

Tags: pdf, unicode, character-encoding, hebrew

I have a certain PDF file, in Hebrew, that's shown correctly, but when copy-pasting it's Gibberish.
Using [PDF Miner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/) and 'xxd', I can get encoding very similar to Unicode, but with some shift.

The Hebrew word 'מגרסת', which is `{d79e d792 d7a8 d7a1 d7aa}` in Unicode, is encoded here as `{c39e c392 c3a8 c3a1 c3aa}`.

Is it a known encoding?

Of course, I can write a small routine that would change all the `c3` prefixes to `d7`, but I'd rather use 'iconv', if it's possible.

Comment: It seems to be UTF8. See this:

$ cat tmp.txt ; file -i tmp.txt ; xxd tmp.txt
מגרסת
tmp.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
0000000: d79e d792 d7a8 d7a1 d7aa 0a              ...........

Comment: http://blogs.adobe.com/insidepdf/2008/07/text_content_in_pdf_files.html